Fix accidental database change with Alembic
My current database differs from what alembic expects, I think because the database was changed manually.
I thought I could just autogenerate a new revision that fixes the changes but get an error.
Is there an easy way to fix the current changes? Ideally automatically via alembic since there are a lot of changes.
Worst case I can start from scratch, but it would be great to be able to just generate a script that gets rid of the changes only.
1b77a04a48d3 (head)
# alembic heads
1b77a04a48d3 (head)
# alembic revision --autogenerate -m "fix last migration"
Target database not consistent with current codebase:
... A lot of changes here

